# Fabric.js image manipulation using control handler, when an image is cropped and scaled, then next crop operation doesn't applied to previous state

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

In the given fabricjs code, I am developing a cropping and scaling function using image control handler. When image is scaled for first time and then cropped, in this case it is working fine. Then further I scale the cropped image and then trying to crop this state, the image state is set to original one.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Image crop</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@latest/dist/fabric.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="700"></canvas>
  <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
</body>
<script>




  fabric.Object.prototype.cornerStyle = "circle";
  fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
  const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");

  let aspectRatioHorizontal;
  let aspectRatioVertical;

  const UserImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image, {
    type: "userImage",
    disableCrop: false,
    clipPosition: null,
    previousTarget: null,
    cropWidth: 0,
    cropHeight: 0,
    changeWidth: 0,
    changeHeight: 0,
    rightChange: 0,
    bottomChange: 0,
    initialize(element, options) {
      options = options || {};
      options = Object.assign({
        cropHeight: this.height,
        cropWidth: this.width
      }, options);

      if (!("clipPosition" in options) || Object.values(fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS).indexOf(options.clipPosition) === -1) {
        options.clipPosition = fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_MIDDLE;
      }

      this.callSuper("initialize", element, options);

      if (!this.disableCrop) {
        this.applyCrop();
      }
    },

    getCrop(image, size, scaleX, scaleY, trim_from, corner, target) {
      let width = size.width;
      let height = size.height;

      // Calculate the crop width and height based on the provided size
      console.log('scaleX', scaleX, 'scaleY', scaleY)
      let x = this.cropX;
      let y = this.cropY;
     
      let newWidth = Math.min(width, image.width * scaleX);
      let newHeight = Math.min(height, image.height * scaleY);
      
      if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.LEFT_TOP) {
        x = this.cropX;
        y = this.cropY;
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.LEFT_MIDDLE) {
        x = this.cropX;
        y = this.cropY;
        if(this.previousTarget){
          x = target.cropX;
          y = target.cropY;
         }
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.LEFT_BOTTOM) {
        x = 0;
        y = image.height - newHeight;
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_TOP) {
        x = this.cropX + this.cropWidth - newWidth;
        y = this.cropY;
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_MIDDLE) {
        //console.log("thisx ..................", this)
         x = (image.width * this.scaleX  - newWidth)/2;
         y = (image.height * this.scaleY - newHeight)/2;
         
        
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_BOTTOM) {
        x = this.cropX + this.cropWidth - newWidth;
        y = this.cropY + this.cropHeight - newHeight;
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.RIGHT_TOP) {
        x = image.width - newWidth;
        y = 0;
        
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.RIGHT_MIDDLE) {
        x = this.cropX + this.cropWidth - newWidth;
        y = this.cropY + this.cropHeight - newHeight;
      } else if (this.clipPosition === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.RIGHT_BOTTOM) {
        x = image.width - newWidth;
        y = image.height - newHeight;
      
      } else {
        console.error(
          new Error("Unknown clip position property - " + this.clipPosition)
        );
      }

      const scaleToFitWidth = width / this.getBoundingRect().width;
      const scaleToFitHeight = height / this.getBoundingRect().height;
      const scale = Math.max(scaleToFitWidth, scaleToFitHeight);

      newWidth *= scale;
      newHeight *= scale;
    

      return {
        cropX: x,
        cropY: y,
        cropWidth: newWidth,
        cropHeight: newHeight,
      };
    },


    applyCrop(c_position, target) {
      this.clipPosition = c_position || 'center-middle';
      
      
      let trim_from;
      if (
        c_position === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_TOP
        || c_position === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_BOTTOM
      ) {
        trim_from = 'height';
      } else if (
        c_position === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.LEFT_MIDDLE
        || c_position === fabric.UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.RIGHT_MIDDLE
      ) {
        trim_from = 'width';
      }
      if (this.disableCrop) return;

      let boudingRect = this.getBoundingRect();


  
      const crop = this.getCrop(
        this.getOriginalSize(),
        {
          width: this.getScaledWidth(),
          height: this.getScaledHeight(),
        },
        this.scaleX,
        this.scaleY,
        trim_from,
        c_position,
        this.previousTarget
      );

      if (target && c_position === 'center-middle') {
        // Use the previous state for subsequent crops
        crop.width = target.width;
        crop.height = target.height;
        crop.cropWidth = target.cropWidth;
        crop.cropHeight = target.cropHeight;
        crop.cropX = target.cropX;
        crop.cropY = target.cropY;
        crop.scaleX = target.scaleX;
        crop.scaleY = target.scaleY;
        this.previousTarget = crop;
      } else {
        // Clear the previous state if it's not a 'center-middle' crop
        this.previousTarget = null;
      }
      
      this.set(crop);
      this.setCoords();
      console.log('this x------------', this)
      canvas.renderAll();
    },


    _render(ctx) {
      if (this.disableCrop) {
        this.cropX = 0;
        this.cropY = 0;
        this.callSuper("_render", ctx);
        return;
      }

      const width = this.width,
        height = this.height,
        cropWidth = this.cropWidth,
        cropHeight = this.cropHeight,
        cropX = this.cropX,
        cropY = this.cropY;

      ctx.save();
      ctx.drawImage(
        this._element,
        cropX,
        cropY,
        cropWidth,
        cropHeight,
        -width / 2,
        -height / 2,
        width,
        height
      );
      ctx.restore();
    },

    toObject(options) {
      options = options || [];
      return this.callSuper("toObject", [].concat(Array.from(options), ["cropWidth", "cropHeight", "disableCrop"]));
    }
  });

  UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS = {
    LEFT_TOP: "left-top",
    LEFT_MIDDLE: "left-middle",
    LEFT_BOTTOM: "left-bottom",
    CENTER_TOP: "center-top",
    CENTER_MIDDLE: "center-middle",
    CENTER_BOTTOM: "center-bottom",
    RIGHT_TOP: "right-top",
    RIGHT_MIDDLE: "right-middle",
    RIGHT_BOTTOM: "right-bottom"
  }

  UserImage.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    fabric.util.loadImage(object.src, function (img, error) {
      if (error) {
        callback && callback(null, error);
        return;
      }
      fabric.Image.prototype._initFilters.call(object, object.filters, function (filters) {
        object.filters = filters || [];
        fabric.Image.prototype._initFilters.call(object, [object.resizeFilter], function (resizeFilters) {
          object.resizeFilter = resizeFilters[0];
          const image = new fabric.UserImage(img, object);
          callback(image);
        });
      });
    }, null, object.crossOrigin);
  };

  fabric.UserImage = UserImage;
  fabric.UserImage.async = true;

  const controlsUtils = fabric.controlsUtils,
    scaleSkewStyleHandler = controlsUtils.scaleSkewCursorStyleHandler,
    scaleStyleHandler = controlsUtils.scaleCursorStyleHandler,
    scalingEqually = controlsUtils.scalingEqually,
    scalingYOrSkewingX = controlsUtils.scalingYOrSkewingX,
    scalingXOrSkewingY = controlsUtils.scalingXOrSkewingY,
    scaleOrSkewActionName = controlsUtils.scaleOrSkewActionName,
    scalingX = controlsUtils.scalingX,
    scalingY = controlsUtils.scalingY;

  function actionScalingOrSkewingCropHandler(eventData, transform, x, y) {
    //console.log('control utils', controlsUtils)
    const { target, corner } = transform;
    let clip_position = UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER;
    if (corner === 'mt') {
      clip_position = UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_BOTTOM
    } else if (corner === 'mb') {
      clip_position = UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.CENTER_TOP
    } else if (corner === 'ml') {
      clip_position = UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.RIGHT_MIDDLE
    } else if (corner === 'mr') {
      clip_position = UserImage.CLIP_POSITIONS.LEFT_MIDDLE
    }

    let act;
    target.applyCrop(clip_position);
    if (corner === "mr" || corner === "ml") {
      act = scalingXOrSkewingY(eventData, transform, x, y);
    }

    if (corner === "mt" || corner === "mb") {

      act = scalingYOrSkewingX(eventData, transform, x, y);
    }

    return act;
  }

  function actionScalingEquallyCropHandler(eventData, transform, x, y) {
    const { target, corner } = transform;

    if (["tl", "tr", "bl", "br"].indexOf(corner) > -1 && eventData.shiftKey) {
      console.log("center-middle...................")
      target.applyCrop();
    }


    const currentWidth = target.width * target.scaleX;
    const currentHeight = target.height * target.scaleY;

    const newWidth = target.getScaledWidth(); // Calculate the new width based on scaling
    const scaleFactor = newWidth / currentWidth; // Calculate the scale factor

    const cropWidth = target.cropWidth / scaleFactor;
    const cropHeight = target.cropHeight / scaleFactor;

    const cropX = target.cropX + (target.cropWidth - cropWidth) / 2;
    const cropY = target.cropY + (target.cropHeight - cropHeight) / 2;


    target.set({
      width: currentWidth,
      height: currentWidth / scaleFactor,
      cropWidth,
      cropHeight,
      cropX,
      cropY,
    });

    target.applyCrop('center-middle', target);
    // Apply the updated crop
    const action = scalingEqually(eventData, transform, x, y); // Apply scaling action
    return action;
  }


  function render(shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY, fn) {
    const angle = this.angle;

    return function (ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject) {
      if (fabricObject.disableCrop) {
        return controlsUtils.renderCircleControl(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject);
      }

      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(left, top);
      ctx.rotate(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(angle + fabricObject.angle));
      ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";
      ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 6;
      ctx.lineCap = "round";
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
      fn.call(this, ctx)
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }

  function renderLeftOrRight(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject) {
    render.call(this, 0, 0, function (ctx) {
      ctx.moveTo(0, -8);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 8);
    })(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject);
  }

  function renderTopOrBottom(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject) {
    render.call(this, 0, 0, function (ctx) {
      ctx.moveTo(-8, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(8, 0);
    })(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject);
  }

  const userImageControls = {
    mr: new fabric.Control({
      x: 0.5,
      y: 0,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleSkewStyleHandler,
      getActionName: scaleOrSkewActionName,
      actionHandler: actionScalingOrSkewingCropHandler,
      render: renderLeftOrRight
    }),

    ml: new fabric.Control({
      x: -0.5,
      y: 0,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleSkewStyleHandler,
      getActionName: scaleOrSkewActionName,
      actionHandler: actionScalingOrSkewingCropHandler,
      render: renderLeftOrRight
    }),

    mt: new fabric.Control({
      x: 0,
      y: -0.5,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleSkewStyleHandler,
      getActionName: scaleOrSkewActionName,
      actionHandler: actionScalingOrSkewingCropHandler,
      render: renderTopOrBottom
    }),

    mb: new fabric.Control({
      x: 0,
      y: 0.5,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleSkewStyleHandler,
      getActionName: scaleOrSkewActionName,
      actionHandler: actionScalingOrSkewingCropHandler,
      render: renderTopOrBottom
    }),

    tl: new fabric.Control({
      x: -0.5,
      y: -0.5,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleStyleHandler,
      actionHandler: actionScalingEquallyCropHandler
    }),

    tr: new fabric.Control({
      x: 0.5,
      y: -0.5,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleStyleHandler,
      actionHandler: actionScalingEquallyCropHandler
    }),

    bl: new fabric.Control({
      x: -0.5,
      y: 0.5,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleStyleHandler,
      actionHandler: actionScalingEquallyCropHandler
    }),

    br: new fabric.Control({
      x: 0.5,
      y: 0.5,
      cursorStyleHandler: scaleStyleHandler,
      actionHandler: actionScalingEquallyCropHandler
    }),

    mtr: new fabric.Control({
      x: 0,
      y: -0.5,
      actionHandler: controlsUtils.rotationWithSnapping,
      cursorStyleHandler: controlsUtils.rotationStyleHandler,
      offsetY: -40,
      withConnection: true,
      actionName: 'rotate',
    })
  }

  fabric.UserImage.prototype.controls = userImageControls;


  let imgObj = new Image(), image = null;

  imgObj.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
  imgObj.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6JavL8o0BLx1-BXc74ndZdPkLKRCPYQGibA&usqp=CAU";
  imgObj.onload = () => {
    image = new fabric.UserImage(imgObj, { left: 10, top: 50 });
    canvas.add(image);
  }

  const stateCrop = {}


</script>
</html>
```

I have tried to pass the target object when the image is scaled to applyCrop function so that for next manipulation it should be the state.

Comment: that is a LOT of code can you reduce that to a minimal example

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I am using custom control ,  I want to use mt, mr, ml, mb corner for crop and scale both. And tl, tr, bl and br corners for the scaling only. Hence this code include all the logic.The issue is with crop and scaling so i thought it is helpful for complete insight

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a cropping tool, implemented through native dom instead of fabric.js. You can try it to see if it meets your needs.
https://github.com/zxf9397/image-cropper

```
npm i icropper
```

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric';
import { FabricCropListener } from 'icropper';

const cropButton = document.querySelector('#crop-btn') as HTMLButtonElement;
const confirmButton = document.querySelector('#confirm-btn') as HTMLButtonElement;
const cancelButton = document.querySelector('#cancel-btn') as HTMLButtonElement;

(async () => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  canvas.width = 600;
  canvas.height = 600;
  canvas.style.setProperty('border', `${2}px solid`);
  const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);

  function fabricImageFromURL(url: string, imgOptions?: fabric.IImageOptions) {
    return new Promise<fabric.Image>((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        fabric.Image.fromURL(url, resolve, { ...imgOptions, crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  }

  const image = (await fabricImageFromURL('/gallery/pic.png', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    scaleX: -0.6,
    scaleY: -0.5,
    angle: 0,
    flipX: true,
    flipY: true,
  })) as Required<fabric.Image>;

  fabricCanvas.add(image).renderAll();

  const listener = new FabricCropListener(fabricCanvas, { containerOffsetX: 604, containerOffsetY: 2 });

  cropButton.addEventListener('click', listener.crop.bind(listener));
  confirmButton.addEventListener('click', listener.confirm.bind(listener));
  cancelButton.addEventListener('click', listener.cancel.bind(listener));
})();
```